# Why is that difference between Math.Round rounding and placeholder rounding in C#?

Tags: c#, rounding, placeholder, difference

please look at these 2 simple codes and the difference in the outputs.

```
using System;

namespace _02.CircleArea
{
    class CircleArea
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double inputR = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double circleArea = Math.Round((Math.PI * inputR * inputR), 12);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", circleArea);
        }
    }
}
```

With an input of **123.456** the output is **47882.2198038791**

And that way of doing it:

```
using System;

namespace _02.CircleArea
{
    class CircleArea
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double inputR = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double circleArea = (Math.PI * inputR * inputR);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:F12}", circleArea);
        }
    }
}
```

With the same input **123.456** it gives the different output **47882.219803879100**

Why is that difference between placeholder rounding and Math.Round rounding results?

Comment: @CodeCaster: The difference discussed in that question is not being observed here.

Comment: The default formatting you get from {0} ensures that the displayed result has never more than 15 significant digits.  Because displaying more would be nonsense, the *double* type can't store that many digits.  It uses 53 bits for its mantissa, that permits only expressing 2^53 distinct values.  When you use F12 then you override the nonsense rule and get 17 digits.  The last two are just random noise, you are unlucky that they are 0.  That can happen, it is an accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.Round` actually gives you a new numeric value, while using format codes just *displays* a rounded value. Since you specify 12 digits of precision in the second format string but not the first, it gives you trailing zeros.

I would note that numeric formatting always rounds *away from zero*, while `Math.Round` by default rounds to the *nearest even number*.

Answer (score 2):

Both rounded exactly the same.  The difference is in the display of trailing zeros.  Since in the first code snippet the number of significant digits is used only for rounding and unavailable to the string formatting routine, it's no surprise that you didn't get trailing zeros.

Comment: @DStanley: Which would appear with other inputs.  *With these inputs*, both rounded exactly the same using both functions.  The question being asked is about the behavior with these inputs, which is the trailing zeros or lack thereof.

Comment: OK I see what you meant.  Deleted my comment.